How to find the library deep_sort_pytorch?
I am trying to execute a repo that I found in git hub, and in the execution of the code I got this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Medeiros\Desktop\YOLO_7\YOLOv7\YOLOv7-DeepSORT-Object-Tracking\deep_sort_tracking_id.py", line 18, in <module>
    from deep_sort_pytorch.utils.parser import get_config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deep_sort_pytorch'

Does anyone know the library deep_sort_pytorch? If this library exists, how can I install?
I can't find the library

I would start by asking the maintainer of the repo.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
